# loop through customers and/or orders in Shopify using liquid code

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm new to liquid code and shopify, and I would like to know if it's possible to make a loop through customers and/or orders ?

I tried the code below without success:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
  {% for order in customer.orders %}
    {{ order.order_number }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for order in orders %}
  {{ order.order_number }}
{% endfor %}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Shopify, for rendering a customer-facing store, you can use Liquid.

In your Liquid examples provided, the assumption is that there are Customers. That makes no sense from a client-side perspective. You can only view the single logged in customer as:

```
{{ customer }}
```

Assuming one is logged in of course. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Secondly, if you do have a customer, then of course, you can see their orders. To present all the orders to a customer, their orders, you get

```
{{ customer.orders }}
```

So you can loop through those orders for a customer, assuming the customer exists, and has orders.

The docs are nice. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects

Comment: Thanks for the answer David.